# TypeError: Cannot read property 'client_secret' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api

I'm trying to follow Google's Node API to access gmail [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs).

When running their sample quickstart as `node quickstart.js`, I am given the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'client_secret' of undefined
    at authorize (/home/user/example/quickstart.js:32:43)
    at processClientSecrets (/home/example/bstick/quickstart.js:21:3)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:439:3)
```

- I have downloaded the key and renamed it `client_secret.json`, and copied it to working directory of `quickstart.js`
- `node --version` = `7.8.0`, package.json has `"google-auth-library": "^0.10.0",
  "googleapis": "^19.0.0"`

Source code(Google's example):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth) {
  var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var labels = response.labels;
    if (labels.length == 0) {
      console.log('No labels found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Labels:');
      for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var label = labels[i];
        console.log('- %s', label.name);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: what is this line of code where the error is happening `quickstart.js:32:43`?

Comment: That's in the authorize function. SPecifically: `var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret`

Comment: ok, how's the `client_secret.json` is loaded?

Comment: If you check the link in the original post, you can see their quickstart.js code. I'm updating it with the question here too.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing the code. Can you `console.log(credentials)` inside the `authorize` function

Comment: Credentials logs the content of the .json file, so that looks to be parsing correctly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you must have selected something other than OAuth while generating the credentials.

So as per the steps 
your config file should look like this

```
{"installed": //whatever
```

But if u select Web, then your config file will look like this

```
{"web":{ //whatever
```

So open your config file & based on that change this line.

```
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
//it should be credentials.whatever-key.client_secret.
//Example : If its web then this line should be credentials.web.client_secret.
```

Comment: I think you're right, the issue might be with the credential generation. I have neither installed nor web in the json, though.

Comment: @cbll what does the client_secret.json say ? is it blank file ? if u have downloaded & Kept, there must be something in it

Comment: It's from a "service account" - going through the tutorial that's what the wizard let me to?

Comment: correct, but if you open the file : there must be some JSON inside it, what is the object key there ?

Comment: I just redid it; Now I have the one with "web" and "client id" keys - I still get the same error, though

Comment: Yeah I changed `installed` to `web`, as per the other answer. New error though - `var redirectUrl = credentials.web.redirect_uris[0];
                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
`

Comment: Meaning : your json file is still not generated properly. it should have something like this `"redirect_uris":["urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob","http://localhost"]}`

Comment: Ahh... I didn't select "Other", I chose Node.. SInce it was a node guide. My bad. Should've read more carefully.

Comment: @cbll : heh heh .. It happens, Glad to Help :)

Answer (score 7):

2020 Update:
The "Other" application type no longer exists. But the "Desktop" option provides the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You have either generated the wrong type of credential (see Parth Ghiya's answer) or selected the wrong type of application.

Do the following:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
   and click `Create credentials` button.
2. Choose `OAuth client ID` option
3. Select application type: `Other`
   (**not `Web application`!**)
4. Give it a name and click `Create`
5. Close popup (which shows client ID and client secret)
6. Click the download icon on your freshly created Credential in the *OAuth 2.0 client IDs* list
7. move the downloaded *.json* file to your project folder
8. rename the file to `client_secret.json`
9. run `node quickstart.js`

You should be good to go.